# PASS_MIN_LEN missing from login.defs

Tags: security, configuration, login, password

I've noticed that the `PASS_MIN_LEN` is missing from the *password aging controls* section inside `/etc/login.defs` (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS). At the end of the file there is a note that it's obsolete, alongside other options, and someone needs to edit the appropriate file in `/etc/pam.d` directory.

```
################# OBSOLETED BY PAM ##############
#                       #
# These options are now handled by PAM. Please  #
# edit the appropriate file in /etc/pam.d/ to   #
# enable the equivelants of them.
#
###############
```

But even if I `cat /etc/pam.d/* | grep "PASS_MIN_LEN"` I still cannot find this option!

What's up with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Pluggable Authentication Modules (PAM)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man7/pam.7.html) is a (not really) newer [generic API for authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluggable_authentication_module) originally proposed by Sun Microsystems in 1995 and adapted a year later on the Linux ecosystem. With an API change, don't expect things to keep the same name (nor to always map exactly the same).

from [`man pam_unix`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man8/pam_unix.8.html):

> **OPTIONS**
>
> [...]
>
> `minlen=n`
> Set a minimum password length of n characters. The default
> value is 6. The maximum for DES crypt-based passwords is 8 characters.

Implementation can vary from distribution to distribution. On Ubuntu (like on Debian), `/etc/pam.d/passwd` will source `/etc/pam.d/common-password` where the first `password` occurence includes the useful options. It can be altered and have an `minlen=X` parameter added. This later file is autoregenerated by [`pam-auth-update`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man8/pam-auth-update.8.html) typically on upgrades, so check it works after an upgrade of PAM-related packages. Normally [it should](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man8/pam-auth-update.8.html):

> The script makes every effort to respect  local  changes  to
> `/etc/pam.d/common-*`. **Local modifications  to  the  list of module
> options will be preserved**, and additions of modules within the managed
> portion of the stack will cause pam-auth-update  to  treat  the
> config files  as  locally  modified and not make further changes to
> the config files unless given the `--force` option.

Other options might still affect the result. Eg, if you set `minlen=1`, the `obscure` option will still reject a one-letter password as a palindrome, or a 2-letters password as too simple etc.

Be careful when altering PAM: you might lock yourself out of your system in case of wrong settings.